# Storing generated documents that can not be updated by changes in relationships

Tags: postgresql, performance, relational-theory

I have a system running with PostgreSQL and Yii Framework, which generates a few medical documents that, once ready, can't be changed. For example: If my full name comes out on this document today, and then I change this tomorrow, that document from yesterday can't get my "new name". It's like I need to have two versions: 1.0, with my old name, and the 1.1, with the new one. that's what I thought first:

1. Store the generated PDF. But I think that would occupy unnecessary space and prevent queries "in" document.
2. store in a plain text like a JSON in a text field

what's really clear to me is that it would not be possible to do this mechanism without avoiding the relationships between the tables. I also believe that storing the each field document in a table field to be a problem, because there are many multiple fields (documents can be up to 150 pages).

Hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: You need a table with at least 3 Columns. 1. DocumentName, 2. Version, 3 Path.  1 and 2 are self explanatory. 3 Should be a String, that is only writable by the database, so that no users can delete the data files, i.e C:\Data\DocumentV1.pdf, and only the Database can sore items in C:\Data.  Users can only read data.

Comment: @ECarterYoung, thanks for the answer. So do you think the "PDF" way is the best choice?

Comment: That's up to you, but personally a pdf once output cannot be modified unless you have the tools to do so. In most instances, you'll know who those people are, which minimizes data loss, and increases control.

Comment: Since the Path in column 3, is only writable by the database, the only way actual people can modify and resave documents in that directory is if they are given write access, which someone will know, if not you.